# php aggregating objects, need explanation

Tags: php, object

I have this example provided by book:

```
class Address {
    protected $city;

    public function setCity($city) {
        $this -> city = $city;
    }

    public function getCity() {
        return $this -> city;
    }
}

class Person {
    protected $name;
    protected $address;

    public function __construct() {
        $this -> address = new Address;
    }

    public function setName($name) {
        $this -> name = $name;
    }

    public function getName() {
        return $this -> name;
    }

    public function __call($method, $arguments) {
        if (method_exists($this -> address, $method)) {
            return call_user_func_array(
                    array($this -> address, $method), $arguments);
        }
    }
}
$rasmus=new Person;
        $rasmus->setName('Rasmus Lerdorf');
        $rasmus->setCity('Sunnyvale');
        print $rasmus->getName().' lives in '.$rasmus->getCity().'.';
```

However I have problem understanding this code.

How does he use __construct to agreggate object and why does he need __call function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`__construct` is the constructor for the `Person` class and is what instantiates each `Person` object.

`__call` allows the `setCity` method to be called on an object of type `Person`. The class `Person` does not possess a method named `setCity`, but by using `__call`, it passes that method call to the `$address` instance variable which is of type `Address`. The `Address` class contains the actual definition of `setCity`.

Both are PHP magic functions:
http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php

Answer (score 2):

When you create a new object **Person** `__construct` magic method is always executed, which sets new property `$address` to an instance of `Address` class.
Magic method `__call` is called every time you call non-existent method of the **Person** class. The **Person** class has no `getCity` method. Therefore it tries to call the same name method (`getCity`) of `$address` object. 
Also it checks if the method exists in the **Address** class, so, if you call `$rasmus->getStreet()`, it won't be executed, as there is no `getStreet` method defined in the **Address** class.

Answer (score 1):

An aggregate object is an object that contains other objects. The `__construct` method in the Person class creates an Address object which is then stored as a property.

The __call method is a so-called 'magic method' which happens every time a method is called on the object that does not exist. In your code you are calling `$rasmus->getCity()`. This method does not exist in the Person class, so when you try calling it, it will actually call the `__call` method.

Inside the `__call` method the code is trying to detect whether that method exists in the Address object - if it does, it calls it.

Therefore, when you call `$rasmus->getName()` it is calling the `Person->getName` method, but when you call `$rasmus->getCity()`, it actually calls the `Address->getCity` method.